# Is there a way to combine import and from import in one statement?

Tags: python, python-import

Is there a way to combine import and from import in one statement?

Can:

```
from random import choice
import random
```

be combined into one statement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, they can't.

See the [`import` statement grammar](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement):

> ```
> import_stmt     ::=  "import" module ["as" name] ( "," module ["as" name] )*
>                      | "from" relative_module "import" identifier ["as" name]
>                      ( "," identifier ["as" name] )*
>                      | "from" relative_module "import" "(" identifier ["as" name]
>                      ( "," identifier ["as" name] )* [","] ")"
>                      | "from" module "import" "*"
> ```

The `import module` and `from relative_module import` forms are two entirely separate forms in the grammar.

Answer (score 4):

I think MartijnPieters was a little hasty.  It is true that it is weird, but here is one way:

```
random, choice = (lambda x: (x, x.choice))(__import__("random"))
```

You see, `__import__("random")` returns the `random` module object.  We then pass that to a `lambda` function.  That `lambda` function returns the module and the module's `choice` attribute as a tuple.  We then assign `random` and `choice` to that tuple.  I would never use this in regular code, but you *can* do it this way.  I would do:

```
import random
choice = random.choice
```